# Запятая перед «или» в сложном предложении

Tags: пунктуация

Имеется следующее предложение:

> Не каждый задумывался о том, можно ли ставить телевизор на холодильнике **(?)** или это опасно?

Интересует место, помеченное вопросительным знаком.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Не каждый задумывался **о том**, можно ли ставить телевизор на холодильнике,  или это опасно.

Всё верно: однородные изъяснительные придаточные, повторяющийся союз ЛИ...ИЛИ, запятая ставится. **Но вот указательное слово "о том" желательно оставить,** так как в словаре указаны предлоги для глагола "задуматься" (над чем, о чём).

**ЗАДУМАТЬСЯ**, св. 1. **над чем, о чём.** Начать размышлять. Начать размышлять. Задуматься **над** задачей. Задуматься **над** собственной жизнью. Задуматься **о** будущем. // **без дополн**. Погрузиться в раздумье, впасть в задумчивость. З. серьёзно, глубоко.  2. **обычно с инф.** (чаще с отриц.). Обнаружить нерешительность в чём-л.; заколебаться. Не задумался сказать правду.

Comment: неужели Вам не режут слух такие конструкции : "о том, или А, или Б", "о том, А ли, или Б"?

Comment: Задуматься и думать - разные глаголы. Можно сказать "думаю, что....", но нельзя сказать (задумываюсь,  что.."

Comment: Sibylla, извините, не улавливаю никакой свази между моим комментарием и Вашим. Я ничего не говорил о глаголах. Поставьте существительное, глагол, все равно.  "собщение о том, А ли, или Б", "задумываюсь о том , А ли, или Б", "думаю о том , А ли, или Б" - все режет слух!

Comment: Я полагаю, что  в  СПП  с придаточным изъяснительным НЕПЕРЕХОДНЫЙ глагол  "задуматься" должен иметь указательное слово  "о том", и это БОЛЕЕ ТОЧНАЯ грамматическая форма. Варианты без указательного слова  мне кажутся  упрощенными и характерными для разговорной речи. Интересно то, что в этом случае можно вместо запятой поставить двоеточие или тире, то есть оформить предложение как БСП. Можно также посчитать главную часть «я задумался» вводным предложением.

Comment: В Нацкорпусе  частотность варианта (я задумался о том…) заметно выше. Сравнить: В то же время я задумался о том, так ли я близок к славянофилам, как мне казалось… или нет?.. [К. Н. Леонтьев (1875) .Я задумался, может ли он причесываться, не снимая шляпы. [Сергей Довлатов (1986)].  В любом случае  заданное предложение с указательным словом звучит вполне корректно, вряд ли стоит его исправлять.

Comment: Я не против "задумался о том, можно ли ставить телевизор на холодильник", "задумался о том, можно ли ставить телевизор на холодильник или нет", но я против двух придаточных типа "о том, А ли, или Б".  Ваши примеры с ИЛИ другой структуры, в них нет второго придаточного, они не убеждают. Не могу сослаться на правила, но доверяю своему чувству языка. Вот, например, так я бы не сказал: "задумался о том, (А) так ли я близок к славянофилам, как мне казалось, или (Б) я еще от них далек"

Comment: ЛИ как бы вводит предмет ваших размышлений "задумался (о чем?) о том, можно ли ставить телевизор на холодильник" и вдуг ни с того ни с сего появляется вторая мысль ("или это опасно?"), она не связана с этим ЛИ.

Comment: К сожалению, наше  чувство языка - не довод для окружающих, и надо объяснять грамматику. А согласно грамматике, указ. слово в изъяснительных придаточных ФАКУЛЬТАТИВНО, но вот есть особый подвид этих придаточных (вмещающие СПП), где оно обязательно. Например: "Это говорит о том, что вопрос еще не решен окончательно".  Поэтому  приходится думать об обязательности или факультативности  местоимения в каждом  случае (в том числе с помощью чувства языка), но для других надо привести хотя бы какой-нибудь грамматический анализ. Мне, кстати, тоже на слух не понравился вариант без местоимения.

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых телевизор ставят на холодильник, а не на холодильнике. Во-вторых, фраза неудачно составлена. Предлагаю такой вариант

**Не каждый задумывался: можно ставить телевизор на холодильник или это опасно.**

Двоеточие оправдано тем, что это бессоюзное сложное предложение, придаточная часть расширяет главное:

**Не каждый задумывался (вот о чем): можно ставить телевизор на холодильник или это опасно.**

Поясню, почему нет запятой перед ИЛИ. То, что стоит после двоеточия - это сложносочиненное предложение с союзом ИЛИ. По Розенталю, перед союзами *и, да* (в значении *и*), *или*, *либо* запятая не ставится, если части сложносочиненного предложения объединены каким-либо общим элементом. Общей может быть поясняемая двумя частями сложносочиненного предложениия третья часть, предшествующая им и связанная с ними бессоюзной связью. Например: 
**Берегов не видать: их скрыла ночь и оттолкнули куда-то широкие волны разлива** (М. Г.);

В конце предложения я поставил точку. Я не вижу здесь прямого вопроса, поэтому считаю, что знак вопроса здесь неуместен. Для сравнения, следующее предложение содержит прямой вопрос: **Спрашивается теперь: что же делало наше общество в последние 20— 30 лет?** (Доброл.);

**Дополнение к ответу**

Елси Вы будете настаивать на Вашей редакции этого предложения (которая кажется мне не очень удачной, но приемлемой в разговорной речи), то правило требует постановки запятой перед ИЛИ.

*Не каждый задумывался о том, можно ли ставить телевизор на холодильник, или это опасно.*

Мне не нравится сочетание О ТОМ с ИЛИ, т.е конструкция "... о том, ... или ...".
В конце-концов пришел в голову подходящий вариант с ЛИ:

**Не каждый задумывался, можно ли ставить телевизор на холодильник, или это опасно.**

Розенталь пишет: Союзы ли…или рассматриваются как повторяющиеся, а потому придаточные части сложноподчиненного предложения, связанные этими союзами, разделяются запятой: **И долго все присутствовавшие оставались в недоумении, не зная, действительно ли они видели эти необыкновенные глаза, или это была просто мечта… (Г.);**

А знак вопроса в такой редакции совсем не нужен.

Comment: спасибо большое!!!

Answer (score 0):

В этом сложном предложении присутствует два придаточных:

1. Безличное, сказуемое — *можно ли ставить*.
2. Личное, подлежащее — *это*, сказуемое — *опасно* (здесь в роли сказуемого выступает наречие).

Вывод: запятая **нужна**, так как необходимо разделять однородные придаточные предложения.

А вот в редактуре (как предлагают другие отвечающие) необходимости не вижу.

Comment: "Опасно" точно не деепричастие. И с разделением придаточных всё не так просто.

Comment: Да, точно, спасибо, это наречие.